# SSRS (SQL2014) - hide a chart when a multi-value parameter is selected

Tags: reporting-services

On one SSRS report, I have a parameter called "Machine". User can select one or several machines in the list.

When only one machine is selected, I want to show a chart.
When several machines are selected, the data shown on the chart makes no sense, so I want to hide the chart.

Do you know how can I detect that user select only one or several machines? Which expression could I use in the "visibility" parameter of the chart?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the visibility property of the chart, use the expression:

```
=(Parameters!ParameterName.Count > 1)
```

This will hide the chart when more than one value is selected.

Comment: I don't know why but "IsMultiValue" does not work; it always hide the chart even if I select only one value.

=(Parameters!ParameterName.Count > 1) works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the visibility property of your table(right click on the whitespace of the table=> properties=> visibility) add this peice of code

`=IIF(Parameters!ParameterName.Count = 1, false, true)`

ParameterName being your multiple-value parameter